# Convert std::vector<double> to matlab setVariable usable array

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have a std::vector of doubles and I need to pass this data to Matlab (to plot). How can I convert the vector into a Matlab readable vector?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-files-1.html

Comment: Call the functions provided by matlab to allocate storage and copy the contents of the `vector` into the given storage.

Comment: @bisherbas this is not a mex file case, I am using matlab graphic capabilities inside c++, therefore minimal usage of matlab is desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.data()` to access the underlying block of memory. Combined with `.size()`, you can get access to a C-like array, which you then pass to MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly this procedure that I used, despite not being clear at Matlab C++ documentation.